# Problem while installing Rocket.chat server

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

I have recently installed a rocketchat server on a 16.04 Ubuntu using the snap option.

The first user I made was admin and after that I created some more. The problem is that I forgot the password of the admin user and I haven't been able to retrieve it or update it.
Because the SMTP settings have not been configured I cannot retrieve the password via email and the option of updating the password via MongoDB to 12345 hasn't seen to work either.

Is there a way via the Linux shell to setup SMTP and this way retrieve the admin password? Any other suggestion is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to delete your user by logging into mongoshell. The users will be available under users collection. You can then create users using ADMIN_USERNAME env variable

https://rocket.chat/docs/administrator-guides/create-the-first-admin/